# Using neural network for visual typography patterns

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Can neural network be used to recognize some visual typography patterns on web pages? Or is there any better way or library to do that (ideally for Java)?

For example, what would be a proper way using neural network to detect product price on some product details page?

And if there's a better way, what would be a better way for doing this?

Comment: Yes, a neural network can be used. Yes, there ís a better way. I hope these answers to your questions will help you and you find a solution soon. No, really, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: How I'm asking a wrong question? And if there's a better way, what is that better way? :)

Comment: Well, if *yes* is the answer and that's sufficient for you, that's ok. I assume you're looking for an answer that explains why and how. But that's not what you asked. BTW: asking for libraries is off-topic.

Comment: No, *yes* is not a sufficient answer. I have updated my initial question.